# std::thread started from a function without waiting the thread to complete

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am confuse to see this small program aborts if I comment `t.join()`

```
void my_thread()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "thread completed\n";
}

void main()
{
    std::cout << "starting thread...\n";
    std::thread t(my_thread);

    t.join();  //<=== my program aborts when I comment this line

    std::cout << "press a key to quit..." << std::endl;
    std::getchar();
}
```

I want to write a function that does not wait the thread to complete.

How should I fix this working example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void my_thread()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "thread completed\n";
}

void send_message()
{
    std::cout << "starting thread...\n";

    std::thread t(my_thread);

    t.join();  //<=== the function aborts when I comment this line
}

void main()
{
    send_message();
    std::cout << "press a key to quit..." << std::endl;
    std::getchar();
}
```

Comment: If you check [a good `std::thread` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) you might find something useful.

Comment: It sounds like you should just use a [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) for this. They are easier and safer.

Comment: Be careful though, if your process exits (by calling `exit` of by returning from `main`) then *all* threads are killed forcibly (which as noted by others isn't the reason for your crash).

Answer (score 3):

If your thread is `joinable` when the destructor is called, then it will call `std::terminate`. You need to either detatch or join.

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread).